# OpenSSH Server: can I split the server configuration into multiple files?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have to problems:

- One System I'm using runs a service that overwrites `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and that service is needed on the system - also the overwrites it does are useful. I want to add a persistent option that doesn't get overwritten.
- I want to be able to split `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that got rather long into multiple files

So my question is: Is there some mechanism like an `/etc/ssh/config.d/` directory for OpenSSH that I can put config files in that all get applied to the eventual ssh config?

Other services that have such a dir:

```
/etc/tmpfiles.d
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
/etc/pam.d
/etc/zfs/zed.d
/etc/modprobe.d
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d
/etc/ipsec.d
/etc/binfmt.d
/etc/docker/cert.d
/etc/sysctl.d
/etc/modules-load.d
```

which makes me thing sshd might have that, too.

Edit:
Using the [`Include`](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2) in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is not a solution, as it would be overwritten by my pesky server service mentioned above.

Comment: The real fix is to make the service stop overwriting `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and start doing this to another file maybe. If you cannot alter its behavior then hopefully you can bind mount another file in a separate mount namespace, so the service (and only the service) sees the other file as `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. If the service creates a new file and moves it to `sshd_config` then you may need to bind mount the `ssh` directory. Anyway, in the real `sshd_config` you will then `Include` the other file in the right place. This is not an answer because I don't know how to do this for a service.

Answer (score 2):

Yes if your sshd version is recent enough.

https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2

> ### Other New Features
>
> - sshd(8): add an Include sshd_config keyword that allows including
>   additional configuration files via glob(3) patterns. bz2468

Free warning: Unlike most config includes you want the sshd include at the top of  your file. The FIRST time a keyword is used wins unlike most conf.d includes where the latest wins.

Comment: There's no "winning" with `Include`. The file is simply included where the directive is used and there can be as many `Include` directives as you like. And you use the `Include` where you want the file to be included. It can be on the top, but it can also be at the bottom, or in the middle.

Comment: Hmm... thanks for the answer, but that `Include` would still get overwritten by my stupid service from the question, right? Because it would have to be in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: if you can't tell your service to generate a conf file with an "Include" I don't think sshd looks by default. You could do some yanky stuff like prepending the Include with an inotify script but that depends on how and when the service generates a new sshd.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Im talking about the "For each keyword, the first obtained value will be used. " bit. If I had "PrintMotd no" in my sshd.conf , and Include as the last line and then "PrintMotd yes" in my custom file I would expect my custom file to win. A bit like sudo. Maybe it's just me that was confused about it :-)